# What is the best implementation for changing the database schema at runtime using Entity Framework 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, multi-tenant

We are building an ASP.Net MVC 2 multi-tenant application on SQL Server using the "single database, separate schema" model discussed, among other places, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) and [here](http://aac2009.confreaks.com/06-feb-2009-14-30-writing-multi-tenant-applications-in-rails-guy-naor.html), where each tenant has one or more users and is split out with its own, tenant specific, SQL Server schema.

The application is using Entity Framework 4.  In order for users for different tenants to access the data in their schema, we need to be able to specify a schema when creating an entity's ObjectContext.

I have seen a few references to this tool (http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/) but (1) I would like to not have to update the code every time the EDMX is generated as specified in the Usage instruction and (2) it was produced before EF4 so I am hoping there is an easier way now.

So, what is the best way to do this in EF4?

Thanks

Comment: Nobody has any ideas?  It is a little disappointing this functionality does not appear to be baked in at all.  It appears that one way to do this is described at http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2008/08/22/change-entity-framework-storage-db-schema-in-runtime.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ok then.  For future searchers, what I have implemented is something like [this example](https://web.archive.org/web/20140502090239/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/27/tip-51-how-to-load-ef-metadata-from-an-arbitrary-stream.aspx), though I load the ssdl, csdl, and msl from the embedded resources like [this example](https://web.archive.org/web/20131020095748/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2008/08/22/change-entity-framework-storage-db-schema-in-runtime.aspx).

In implementation, I when creating a repository object in an MVC action request, I take use a user context to determine what schema is needed, use the previously noted example to write the schema and create an EntityConnection and then use it create my ObjectContext entity.

It seems to function pretty well, though I am a bit concerned that it intuitively seems like it might be a performance problem.