# Multi tenant database with customized schemas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, database-schema, multi-tenant

I am writing a multi tenant application in which each tenant has their own schema in a database or their own database. Because the tenant data is separate I'd like to be able to customize their tables by adding columns, or by creating additional views to meet their specific needs. Ideally, I'd like to make changes without recompiling the code.

This desire seems to run counter to how MVC is intended to work. My question is, can MVC and a multi schema, multi tenant architecture work when the schemas differ from each other slightly? If so, how do I design models that will allow for those variations?

Comment: You may want to look into FubuMVC http://mvc.fubu-project.org/ which is written to be multi tenant with customization required per client.

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille a search for "schema" on their website returned nothing. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to throw this out there in case you haven't stumbled upon it yourself:

http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/05/29/multi-tenant-asp-net-foundation.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this was a good read, but did not cover how to handle when the tables in each of the tenant's schemas differ.

Comment: @Sparafusile have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3270228/1026898 ?  I've never done what you are asking for a solution to and I'm just trying to lessen your suffering a bit.  If you have already read that, I apologize for getting your hopes up with the little Stackoverflow notification.

Comment: I think that's close to what I'm looking for. I had seen the links before, but I guess they didn't sink in. I'll go over them again and see if it will work for what I want.

Comment: I'm learning a bit more about it - if I come across anything I'll update.  For now it just seems that it is such an uncommon need that there is not a super clean way to do it.  I see the possibility for the necessity of a tool / NuGet package to be built to accommodate people in a similar position.

Answer (score 0):

Here at [Citus](http://www.citusdata.com) we're building a distributed/sharded multi-tenant database using PostgreSQL. You can go over our [use-case guide](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v6.2/use_case_guide/multi_tenant.html), which goes over an example application.
We don't shard by schema, but instead shard by the tenant-id. The table is then sharded across multiple nodes. For per-tenant information, we use JSONB, which then allows different tenants to keep different tenant-specific information.